# Adding indentation to multiple lines at once in Python's IDLE

Tags: python, indentation, python-idle

I have written many lines of code already, and have now changed my mind on their indentation. (I want to put all of these lines into a 'while' loop.)

For each line, I could press the space button or tab, but this would take a long time.

Can I add the appropriate indentation/margin to all these lines at once?

Comment: This is an editor problem... what editor are you using?

Comment: you can also write a python script to do it :)

Comment: @gefei : I thinks it's the best solution but I wonder why there is no a regular solution for a such trivial problem !!! Thanks alot:)

Comment: @MehrdadMoharrami you definitely don't need to write a script! Tab in IDLE will insert 4 spaces (by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), highlight text and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to do the opposite i.e. remove one level of indentation). *This will do the same as adding a tab at the beginning of every line.*

These shortcuts is the same in several other text editors, e.g. Notepad++, Eclipse and even Word.

Other editors may use different/additional shortcuts e.g. in <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>) in IDLE (and Sublime Text).

Comment: I know that but this is not a good way to do that. Tab key has different character in different systems. Any other ?

Comment: @MehrdadMoharrami why is it not a good way to do it? Although tab has a different character it still does the same thing in the editor. Do you mean the difference between tab being 2, 4 or 8 spaces? (This behaviour is set in the editor.)

Comment: :you know I have read in some scripts that to never use tab instead of space. for example use four space and don't use one tab instead. it seems that when you change your platform, it can make problem for you. I don't know that it's true or not and I have not examined it.
and one more question. how can I remove spaces from multiple lines? shift+tab didn't work here.

Comment: Which text-editor are you using? You're right it can cause a problem, and this behaviour can be **configured in you editor** (e.g. *a tab will always insert 4 spaces*, which is the default behaviour of Sublime Text).

Comment: Note: this setting is often called "tab width"

Comment: The default "tab width"/indentation width in IDLE is 4 (so tabbing is equivalent to 4 spaces). You can adjust this by `Options>Configure IDLE`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. how can I remove margin of multiple line ? my last one I hope :)

Comment: Highlight text, goto the `format` menu<`dedent region`. This will also tell you the keyboard shortcut to do it. (I think CTL+[ ).

Comment: Thanks so much. It was a great help for me .