# Python IDLE: auto-indent is too large?

Tags: python, indentation

This isn't the same as the question "Changing indentation in Python's IDLE"[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193991/changing-indentation-in-pythons-idle). When writing code IDLE is supposed to indent for the user when you type a line ending in a colon. But in the current version I am using 2.7.3 (not sure if this comes up in other versions), it is indenting five tab stops in. It is extremely jarring and based on samples of code all over the internet I can't imagine jumping five tabs is an accepted standard. The only solution I have found is to backspace through the indents, but IDLE seems to favor starting at col 33.

This is especially irritating because I prefer having multiple smaller windows in view at once and this puts the first indent, after a line of code at column 0, about halfway across the visible area.

Has this come up for anyone else?

addendum: This is in the edit mode for a .py file, not the shell itself.

Comment: The indentation level in IDLE is configurable. Have you gone into the `Options` menu and checked what you have it set to? You might have picked five spaces by mistake.

Comment: That was something I messed with actually, and I was waiting on the time limit to answer my question because I found that the solution was even simpler: a huge indentation jump was being caused by an open paren farther up... it wasn't a blank .py file, it had a couple initialization things earlier on. It wasn't clear to me that was why the indent was happening.

Comment: @SeanCritz Thank you!!! For the past half hour I've been cursed with extremely large auto-indents (in an html file), and I thought it was the new text editor I was using, only to download a different editor and have the same problem. Turns out it was an open tag near the top.

Comment: had this problem to i forgot to close my .write so it was `.write(str(data)`